# Relative URl crawling issue

Tags: go, web-crawler, relative-path, absolute-path

I'm making a crawler that fetches all relative and absolute links. But if there is a relative url that is incorrect, then the crawler continues to prepare new absolute url in the website that handles incorrect urls with 200 response code.

Let's say, there is a relative link : "example/example.php", when I try to crawl http://example.com/example.com. When I find that page, I'll append and create a new link to crawl i.e. http://example.com/example/example.php. The problem is the page will again contain example/example.php which then appends to http://example.com/example/example/example.php.

Is there a better way of getting rid of this other than content comparison?

Comment: No there is not. You cannot know if `href="example/example.php"` is a new, deeper page or a bug in the website. Depending on the server you might be able to tell from the headers (E-Tag?) if you got the same page again.

Comment: You need to compare the content, but it will probably not be identical. You can use a technique such as MinHash (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinHash) or SimHash (http://matpalm.com/resemblance/simhash/) to estimate if it's similar enough to be the same page. That's how most web crawlers work

Comment: Thanks @Not_a_Golfer, I was expecting some other workaround to get this done like  Volker suggested.(Yes, I was unaware about E-tag). Hashing was on my mind. I am thinking of doing hashing only if certain link starts to repeat. I'll look into it

Comment: @Sunil don't count on ETAGS, and anyway, you should use similarity hashing for pages that are the same and have different URLs (think mobile vs. desktop versions of the same page)